# add +1 on click in php

Tags: php, database, sql-update

I have a problem with my incrementation in php.

I try to add a button  "+"  who add +1 when I Click on the button for  my ingredients.

So for example, If I click on +  for "tomatoes" and If in my database I had 50 tomatoes.
Now I have 51 tomatoes

I did it, but the problem is that when I click on "+",   it add me not +1  but +8  ( Maybe because I have 8 ingredients in my database)

Here my code :

```
$nom = 'salade';
$req=$db->prepare("UPDATE ingredients SET stock = stock +1 WHERE nom =:nom");
$req->execute(array('nom' =>$nom));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98uVK.png)

Thanks for reading me !

Comment: If you have multiple rows that meet your `WHERE` clause, then yes, all of those rows will be updated.

Comment: No, I try just for 'salade'  I try add +1  just for salade,  but in salade  it add me +8 and not +1

Comment: Then you have 8 rows containing salade or you click many times. You could add LIMIT 1 to the query or better lock the button.

Comment: no, I edit my post

Comment: just when I clikc on the button stock, It put me "+8"  and not "+1"  for salade

Comment: Even if there are multiple matching rows, I can't see how this code can possibly add 8 to anything unless it's running in a loop or the form is being submitted multiple times. Can you post your full HTML and PHP code?

Comment: @iainn  Well, if there were 8 matching rows, adding 1 to each, and OP was doing a `SUM` when querying, that would do it.  But I agree, we need more information.  Something's going on that we're not being shown.

Comment: yes , it's good it works now,  thx !!     But I would like know,  Why when I do F5  it refresh me the page, but  It add me too +1 ???